# Hyper-V Replica from windows 2012 to windows 2008

Tags: hyper-v, replication

My Customer has two hyper-v foc with san storage. one is built on windows 2008 datacenter and the new one is built on windows 2012 datacenter.
can I make a hyper-v replica from a windows 2012 hyper-v to the old windows 2008 cluster, or do I have to upgrade the old cluster to windows 2012 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V Replica was introduced in Windows Server 2012, so no, you won't be able to set it up with your Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V FoC.

Comment: I second this. Besides, in Hyper-V Replica requirements there are "You’ll need two servers running Windows Server 2012 or Windows Server 2012 R2 with the Hyper-V role." https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134172(v=ws.11).aspx